# Python watchdog: what is the 'empty' directory snapshot?

Tags: python, diff, directory-structure, snapshot, watchdog

Watchdog is pretty awesome at letting you take recursive snapshots of a particular directory. It even lets you compare snapshots with a function called [DirectorySnapshotDiff](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.utils.dirsnapshot.DirectorySnapshotDiff).

My program watches as a directory evolves in real-time, and thus has been made to consume the output of this function. This is very reasonable.

Let's say I take snapshots `s1, s2...` of the file system at arbitrary times. We compare the last snapshot with the latest one to create difference objects.

```
        d1    d2           # detected differences (my app eats these up)
     s1 -> s2 -> s3        # evolving states (snapshots taken) of the file system.

t=0 -------------------> time
```

Omnomnomnom. That's great.

But, the first time I run my app, I need to know the current state. I want to pretend that there was a null state `s0`, which transitions into `s1`; thus I can diff format. i.e.

```
     d0                # I want to create this 'bootstrapping' difference set
(s0) -> s1             # Assume s0 is the empty snapshot: it reports everything is an addition
```

How do I do that?

The motivation behind this is: I love functional programming. Instead of writing code to consume snapshots AND snapshot diffs (both considerable work) I like to keep reuse high and code minimal.

Comment: the question doesn't seem complete?

Comment: Pardon me, I hit enter before finishing =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For versions of python >= 2.6 watchdog uses it's OrderedSet.

Modify fatuhoku's paths function as follows;

```
@property
def paths(self):
    if sys.version_info >= (2, 6, 0):
        return watchdog.utils.bricks.OrderedSet()
    return set()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution by making a class that mimics `watchdog.utils.dirsnapshot.DirectorySnapshot`, returning empty values where appropriate.

```
class EmptyDirectorySnapshot(object):
    """
    For use as the zeroth snapshot in a chain of DirectorySnapshotDiffs
    """

    @property
    def stat_snapshot(self):
        return {}

    def stat_info(self, path):
        return None

    @property
    def paths(self):
        return set()
```

The two properties `stat_snapshot` and `paths`, as well as the method `stat_info` given above are used in the diffing function. This works fairly well and yields intended results. Hurrah.